# How do i create a disc that will install a custom program?

Tags: installation, disc

Backstory
     I am creating a java 2d game for my year 12 major project. This project contains a section detailing that i need to package this game as if i was selling it as a commercial product, including case, manual and disc.

What i want the disc to do
     I would like it to generally install my game to the given directory assuming the given conditions have been met. Once installed, the disc dose not need to be used.

I have further functionality that i would like for my disc, however i think i should wait until i get this set finished.

As a summary, how do i code a disc to automatically install my game when put in the computer

I hope this was the correct place as this question, if you can answer please do, the more detailed the better. All input is appreciated. Even where to look as i have had no luck over 3 weeks.

Thanks to all in advance
    -zephyr

Comment: Is this specific to Windows?

Comment: I would preferable like it to work on windows, apple and linux as the game has to be completely un-bias to any user. However, if you can only provide a windows solution then i will more then happily take it :)

Comment: You will also have to ensure the target computer already has java installed (JDK or JRE) and if it the right version and if not install java as well as your game ...

Comment: Yep great thanks, that would be awesome, ill keep that in mind thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, you can simply achieve it using an `autorun.inf` file in the root folder of your disc. All you need to do is, create a text file at the root folder of your disc, name it as `autorun.inf` and configure as to which EXE you want to execute when the disc is inserted.

Lets, say you want to run `Setup.exe` (also present in the root folder), below will be the file contents of autorun.inf,

```
[autorun] 
open=Setup.exe
```

You can read more about it [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/818804)

Comment: Thanks thats heaps good :), is the startup exe able to be created in visual basic? Eg so i can create a program to install the game from their?

Comment: you are welcome, glad it helped. The startup exe can be any windows executable.

Comment: Sweat, ill start making it right away :)

Comment: Last question, is their some other combination of files that i will need for this to work on linux and mac?